# Initialize C++ array2 using constant array1 known at compile time

Tags: c++, c++11, compiler-errors, constants, constant-expression

I have the following array:

```
int const A[4] = { 0, 1, 2, 3 };
```

I want to initialize a duplicate array, as follows:

```
int a[4] = A;
```

If I run g++ 4.8.2 on cygwin as follows:

```
g++ --std=c++11 myfile.cpp
```

I get the following error:

```
myfile.cpp:16:16: error: array must be initialized with a brace-enclosed initializer
    int a[4] = A;
               ^
```

However, evidently "`int a[4] = { A };`" isn't going to work either. Is there a way to initialize my array `a` from `A` using a simple assignment statement without resorting to:

```
int a[4] = { A[0], A[1], A[2], A[3] };
```

?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use instead standard class `std::array`.

```
#include <array>

//...

const std::array<int, 4> A = { 0, 1, 2, 3 };
std::array<int, 4 > a = A;
```

Answer (score 7):

```
std::copy(A, A+4, a)
```

or, by using std::array has the easy copy method you want:

```
std::array<int, 4>A = {0, 1, 2, 3}
std::array<int, 4>a = A;
```

Comment: Thanks @Ben! I accepted @Vlad from Moscow's just because it's the exact answer I wanted, but yours is basically identical and I appreciate the time.